# Upload file to server amazon S3 without multipart file corrupted

Tags: android, retrofit

Uploading file to amazon S3.
Using PUT, without multipart, with dynamic Url, Creating url encoding issue, File is corrupted issue.

Answer (score 1):

I struggle a lot, There are answers but distributed here and there. It took my one and half day, So I am pasting solution here. So that others can save their time.

@PUT()
fun uploadDocument(
@Url upload_url: String, @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>,
@Body requestBody: RequestBody
): Call

headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/msword")

1. reading file:

val inputStream = assets.open("testdoc.docx")  // reading file from asset

```
    var size = inputStream.available()

    val buffer = ByteArray(size)
    var bytesRead: Int
    val output = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    }

    val byteArray = output.toByteArray()
    val requestBody= 
               RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/msword"), byteArray)
```

2. calling:
   JMAServiceInstance.serviceInterfaceForDoc.uploadDocument(
   Utils.upload_Url,headerMap,requestBody)

// Points to remember : Don't use @Path, Url will be encrypted and you will get bad request error. directly use @Url inside the function.